# Java Classpath Issues - will not run

Tags: java, classpath

I'm learning how to run Java from the command line, and keep running into the same issue. The `main()` method I'm running is in `bin/edu/cuny/util/ConvertTestVectors.class`.

I set my directory to `bin/cuny/`. When I run `> java -cp . ConvertTestVectors` I get:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class ConvertTestVectors
```

When I run `>  java -cp . util/ConvertTestVectors` I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: util/ConvertTestVectors (wrong name: edu/cuny/util/ConvertTestVectors)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:480)
```

Could someone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To run a `main` method of some java class you have to specify the fully qualified name of this class in the command line. For example, if you have in your source:

```
package edu.cuny.util;

class ConvertTestVectors {
    ...
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

then to run this `main` method you should use

```
java edu.cuny.util.ConvertTestVectors
```

If your package name is different, you should change the class name in command line accordingly.

Also, there is a `CLASSPATH` variable, which determines the location where java looks for classes. It should contain the directory where the root of your java packages in located (the parent directory of `edu` is case of the previous example). If it contains `.` then you can just change directory to that root directory and run java command.

The parts of a fully qualified class name are separated by dots (`.`) so you should not use slashes (`/`) in class name

Comment: That's why the OP used -cp . ;)

Answer (score 1):

`cd bin/edu/cuny && java util.ConvertTestVectors`

You have to use the full package name.

Comment: Thanks. But that's what gives me the second error, the NoClassDefFoundError.

Comment: You said you got the second error from `util/ConvertTestVectors`, not `util.ConvertTestVectors`.

Comment: I changed the `/` to a `.` and it didn't matter.

Comment: What package is the class in then?

Comment: Got it! The other answer, which the user deleted, solved the problem. When I run `java edu.cuny.util.ConvertTestVectors` from `bin` it takes care of it. Thanks so much for your help, though!